# XMLPullParser not finding START_TAGs

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I am attempting to parse XML data from the following URL

[Traffic Scotland Current Incidents](https://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/currentincidents.aspx)

Right now, I have an app that, on button press, gets the XML data, attempts to parse it, and then just displays the raw xml data as I can't currently parse anything.

As far as I can tell, the code below *should* work, and I'm at a loss for why it doesn't. It seems to go straight from START_DOCUMENT (eventType 0) to END_DOCUMENT (eventType 1).

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view == ciButton)
        viewCI();

    if (view == prButton)
    {
        viewPR();
    }
}

public void viewCI()
{
    new Thread(new Task(urlCI)).start();
}

public void viewPR()
{
    new Thread(new Task(urlPR)).start();
}

class Task implements Runnable
{
    private String url1;
    private String text;

    Incident incident = null;
    ArrayList<Incident> incidents = null;

    public Task (String aUrl)
    {
        url1 = aUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String inputLine;
        Log.e("MyTag","in run");

        try
        {
            Log.e("MyTag","in try");

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            int lineNum = 0;
            //Skips first line of XML feed
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNum++;
                if (lineNum > 1)
                {
                    result = result + inputLine;
                }
            }

            xpp.setInput(uc.getInputStream(),null);

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                Log.e("MyTag","in while");
                Log.e("MyTag",Integer.toString(eventType));
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    Log.e("MyTag","Start Doc");
                }
                else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {
                    String tag = xpp.getName();
                    Log.e("MyTag","Start tag: "+tag);
                }
                else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                {
                    String tag = xpp.getText();
                    Log.e("MyTag","End Tag: "+tag);
                }
                else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                {
                    String tag = xpp.getText();
                    Log.e("MyTag","Text: "+tag);
                }


                Log.e("MyTag","xpp.next");
                eventType = xpp.next();
                Log.e("MyTag","ET after next: "+Integer.toString(eventType));
            }

        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException xppe)
        {
            Log.e("MyTag","XPPE: ");
            xppe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("MyTag", "IOE");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
                urlInput.setText(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the code above, I log the following:

> 02-21 09:17:52.201 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag: in run
>   02-21 09:17:52.232 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag: in try
>   02-21 09:18:00.092 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag: in
>   while
>   02-21 09:18:00.092 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag: 0
>   02-21 09:18:00.092 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag: Start Doc
>   02-21 09:18:00.092 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag:
>   xpp.next
>   02-21 09:18:00.092 3258-3572/com.example.chdick.pullparsertest2 E/MyTag: ET after next: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xpp.setInput(uc.getInputStream(),null);
```

That is the second time you use `uc.getInputStream()`. You already read the whole stream. You already got the whole document in `String result`.

You cannot read the stream a second time. You cannot read the document a second time. It will indicate the end of stream right away if you try.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! If it's not too much trouble could I ask how to parse tags with a colon in them? For example `<georss:point>57.536904 -6.203359</georss:point>`, I tried comparing the tag to both `georss` and `georss:point`, neither worked. Do I need to get the prefix? Or could I do .contains()?

Comment: Dont know. Never used that parser.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried? Is eventType TEXT not triggered? Or does getText() fail? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The error I get is `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: undefined prefix: georss (position:START_TAG <{null}georss:point>@1:831 in java.io.StringReader@8b5fbd4)`. The stack trace gives `eventType = xpp.next();` as the line that causes the error. At first, I tried just doing `tag.equalsIgnoreCase("georss")` or `georss:point` or just `point`, but those all got the same error. I have tried googling solutions, and it hasn't exactly been helpful. This is the line in the XML file that seems to be causing trouble `<georss:point>57.536904 -6.203359</georss:point>`.

Comment: Actually ignore that, I was not reading in the first two lines of the XML file as a friend suggested, and that's where the prefix is defined.